# "as if Jane had wound it round a row of pokers" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a novel called "Howl's Moving Castle" and reached this part were people are mocking a character called Jane for her hair and couldn't understand what "wound" means in this context? and why did she use "round" and not "around"?

> Her hair did look a little strange, Sophie thought, peeping out of her alcove, as if Jane had wound it round a row of pokers.

thank you.

Comment: ***Wound***  is the past participle of ***to wind***: [ T usually + adv/prep ] to wrap something around an object several times or twist it repeatedly around itself:
*She wound a scarf around her neck.
He wound the string into a ball.
He wound a small bandage round her finger.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/wind - round or around are interchangeable here - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/around-or-round

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it meant "injury" so it didn't make any sense.

Comment: Note also that this use of *wound* rhymes with *round* and *sound*, whereas the injury-related *wound* rhymes with *pruned* and *swooned*. :-)

Comment: @user240918 Please take your comment and submit it as an answer so it can be accepted.